# How to store an object in a cookie?

Tags: c#, session, object, cookies, store

While this is possible in C#: (User is a L2S class in this instance)

```
User user = // function to get user
Session["User"] = user;
```

why this is not possible?

```
User user = // function to get user
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie();
cookie.Value = user;
```

and how can it be done? I don't want to store the id of the user within the cookie and then do some validation.

Btw, if possible, is it secure to store an object within a cookie rather than only the ID ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A cookie is just string data; the only way to do that would be to serialize it as a string (xml, json, base-64 of arbitrary binary, whatever), however, you shouldn't *really* trust anything in a cookie if it relates to security information ("who am I?") as a: it is easy for the end-user to change it, and b: you don't want the overhead of anything biggish on every single request.

IMO, caching this as the server is the correct thing; don't put this in a cookie.

Comment: so should I use cache for a basic remember me option?

Comment: @Shaokan absolutely; that could be "session", or a more basic cache. But it doesn't need to go to the client. All the client needs is some random token.

Comment: so basically if each user has a guid which is created on register, and if I store that guid in cookies to remember the user, would that be a safe method ?

Comment: @Shaokan - yes. If it is for full login purposes, you should use normal security procedures (token/series maybe)

Comment: @marc for security reason of data that stored in cookie you can encrypt your string then store it in cookie, obviously you should decrypt after you read it from cookie to use.

Answer (score 13):

You can use JSON

```
string myObjectJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObject);
var cookie = new HttpCookie("myObjectKey", myObjectJson) 
{     
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) 
};
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: Is the best option. I use Newtonsoft.Json. Remember when retrive use: var s = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(cookie.Values["myObjectKey"].ToString());

Comment: Yes, please use Netwonsoft.Json. I only wanted to make a simple answer with the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: Cookies store strings, and not binary objects.

You could serialize your object into strings or JSON if you really wanted to. Suggest keeping the data back/forth as lightweight as you can. Remember: each time we communicate from the browser to the server, you're passing all that data each time.

Answer (score 1):

you could encrypt such a cookie as well.  The contents (json/xml/etc) would be a bit safer then.  Server-side caching as Marc suggests is probably better.

Tradeoff: increased traffic on the wire (cookies are passed back and forth) Vs larger server-side memory footprint and / or secondardy storage.

btw: don't forget that binary can be encoded to text if you really need that.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/TextCoDec.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
StringWriter outStream = new StringWriter();
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<string>>));
s.Serialize(outStream, myObj);
cookie.Value = outStream.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

in cookie you can store a value of type string. you can store your object into session,viewstate  or in cache. but still want to store in cookies, just use system.web.script.javascriptserialization class and convert the whole object in json string and then store that on your cookie.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection cookiecoll = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

            cookiecoll.Add(bizID.ToString(), rate.ToString());


        HttpCookie cookielist = new HttpCookie("MyListOfCookies");
        cookielist.Values.Add(cookiecoll);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookielist);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
public void AddToCookie(SessionUser sessionUser)
    {
        var httpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["SessionUser"];
        if (httpCookie != null)
        {
            httpCookie["ID"] = sessionUser.ID.ToString();
            httpCookie["Name"] = sessionUser.Name;
            httpCookie["Email"] = sessionUser.Email;
            httpCookie["Phone"] = sessionUser.Phone;
            httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to store an object in a cookie we have to convert it into stringified presentation (compressed or not) which is limited to 4kb. this example demonstrates how to keep a little "Buy" object in a cookies (save/prolong/reset/clear). instead of separate code lines i've used a Json to fill this object with some data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class Customer
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
public class Order
{
    public int id;
    public decimal total;
    public Customer customer;
}
public class OrderItem
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public decimal price;
}
public class Buy
{
    public Order order;
    public List<OrderItem> cart;
}
static readonly string cookieName = @"buy";
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (!IsPostBack)
        Restore_Click(null, null);
}
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buy = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        order = new
        {
            id = 1,
            total = 20.10,
            customer = new
            {
                id = 1,
                name = "Stackoverflow"
            }
        },
        cart = new[] {
            new {
                id = 1 , 
                name = "Stack",
                price = 10.05 
            },
            new {
                id = 2 , 
                name = "Overflow",
                price = 10.05 
            }
        }
    });
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(
        new HttpCookie(cookieName, buy) {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
        }
    );
    StatusLabel.Text = "Saved";
}
protected void Prolong_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        StatusLabel.Text = "Prolonged";
    }
    else StatusLabel.Text = "Not prolonged - expired";
}
protected void Restore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Buy buy = null;
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        buy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Buy>(cookie.Value);
        StatusLabel.Text = "Restored";
    }
    else StatusLabel.Text = "Not restored - expired";
}
protected void ClearOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        StatusLabel.Text = "Cleared out";
    }
    else StatusLabel.Text = "Not found - expired";
}
```

Comment: Adding little explanation to answer main ( late ) will be more helpful than just copy/past a code snippet.

Comment: if you do not know to read c# code it doesn't mean you should to downvote, dear Maher Abuthraaaaaaaa

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I didn't downvote you. you code is long relatively and not documented .. I don't know if it will answer the question or not .. Also code-only for me is considered as low quality answer  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Cookie store only strings.
What you can do:

```
 var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 var json = serializer.Serialize(user);
controller.Response.SetCookie(
        new HttpCookie({string_name}, json)
        {
            Expires = false // use this when you want to delete
                    ? DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
                    : DateTime.Now.Add({expiration})
        });
```

This should insert the entire object to cookie.

In order to read from the cookie back to an object:

```
    public static {Object_Name} GetUser(this Controller controller)
    {

        var httpRequest = controller.Request;

        if (httpRequest.Cookies[{cookie_name}] == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var json = httpRequest.Cookies[{cookie_name}].Value;
            var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = serializer.Deserialize<{object_name}>(json);
            return result;
        }

    }
```