# how do i save something in a cookie c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

All i want to save instance of a class in a cookie just to check something.
Here is my code

```
    class khurram { 
khurram k1= new khurram(); 
HttpCookie tcook = new HttpCookie("test");
            tcook.Value = k1;
}
```

but 'tcook' is not present. what am i doing wrong i don't understand.

i also tried

```
[serializable]
class khurram { 
public string str1{get;set;};
}
khurram k1= new khurram(); 
HttpCookie tcook = new HttpCookie("test");
tcook.Value = k1;
```

please help.
thanks in advance

Comment: Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617799/how-to-store-an-object-in-a-cookie) to a similar question.

Comment: why do i have a negative vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined to be of type string - in both of your examples, you appear to be trying to give it a class `khurram`

Someething like this may work better for you:

```
class khurram { 
    public string str1{get;set;};
}

// later ...

khurram k1= new khurram(); 
HttpCookie tcook = new HttpCookie("test");
tcook.Value = k1.str1;
```

Comment: no way dude. tcook is not present there. may be i am missing something. if i write tcook, it gives me error that it is a field and i am using it as a type

Comment: If it gives you an error like that, then something more serious is at fault -- you are writing that later code *within a method*, aren't you?

Comment: done thanks dude. i was putting it outside method. :) now i get it! thanks alot buddy! GOD BLESS!!

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

// Set the cookie value.
myCookie.Value = now.ToString();
// Set the cookie expiration date.
myCookie.Expires = now.AddMinutes(1);

// Add the cookie.
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

Response.Write("<p> The cookie has been written.");
```

Comment: same problem.. "myCookie" is a field but used as a type.

Comment: done thanks dude. i was putting it outside method. :) now i get it! thanks alot buddy! GOD BLESS!!