# Cookie fails to be created in vs express 2013 for web c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

First off, I'm on a Win7 laptop using Chrome in my IE.
I can store the data I have with a session variable but cannot get it to work with a cookie.
I attempt to set the cookie in a button click event and then attempt to read it in a textChanged event. I can see the cookie object get populated in the IE but it never seems to actually get created when I look for it with chrome://settings/cookies.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSubmitQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> geometryList = new List<string>();

     try
     {
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.SqlQri.ConnectionString))
         {
             conn.Open();

             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(this.tbxSQLQri.Text, conn))
             {
                 object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                 Session["polys"] = result.ToString();

                 HttpCookie myPolys = new HttpCookie("polys");   // This seems to work
                 myPolys.Value = result.ToString();
                 myPolys.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                 Response.SetCookie(myPolys);

             }

             conn.Close();
         }
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
         this.tbxSQLQri.Text = "Query Exception";
     }

}
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read Session val
    string looky = (string)(Session["polys"]);
    this.TextBox1.Text = looky;

    string lookyHere = "";

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["polys"] != null)   // This is never true!
    {
        lookyHere = Request.Cookies["polys"].Value;
    }

    this.TextBox2.Text = lookyHere;
}
```

Comment: what is the key that you are trying to get for example you need your `object.Values["someName"] = result.ToString` this line is not correct I believe `myPolys.Value = result.ToString();`

Comment: This is the section where I attempt to read the cookie but I don't see that it is actually created in Chrome:    string lookyHere = "";

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["polys"] != null)   // This is never true!
    {
        lookyHere = Request.Cookies["polys"].Value;
    }

    this.TextBox2.Text = lookyHere;

Comment: you have stated that this is never true `if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["polys"] != null)` then what is the value of this when you are in the debugger..? `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["polys"]`
Please tell me that you are using the debugger too

Answer (score 0):

I declare a Private constant string with the name as follows

```
 private const string cnstLoginCookieName = "Super-User";
```

inside of my Page_load I have the following declared

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie objCookie = new HttpCookie(cnstLoginCookieName);
    objCookie.Values["Login"] = username.Trim();
    objCookie.Values["Company"] = "CoolFirm";
    objCookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
    Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie);
}
```

Comment: I can't set my cookie in Page_Load() as I have to retrieve the data from sql server first in the event section. Tried the const/string without success either.

Comment: I just found something about the Web.config that I didn't have but it didn't make a difference either. <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>

Comment: Page_Load is just an example it the code that you should be able to follow can you explain what values you want the cookie object to be..

Comment: Oh dang, That was the key. If I change the value to "hello world" it works. My previous value was a extremely long string like this:  POLYGON ((-122.143636 47.257808, -122.143685 47.257807, -122.143877 47.257802, -122.143993 47.257799, -122.143989 47.257746, Is there an alternative method for storing big strings of data. I'm trying to write the data in .aspx and read the data in javascript on an html page of the solution.

Comment: can you post that in your original question so that it's more readable

Comment: you should actually not use Cookies personally but if you want to store something like that in a cookie consider using JSON Object and serialize it if you do not understand that then why not just create a class and store the data in a class object..? here is an example of something you could do 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617799/how-to-store-an-object-in-a-cookie

Comment: I also gave you a working example of how to use `Response.Cookies` vs using `Session`

Answer (score 0):

OK, This part of my problem was solved. My string was too long to go in a cookie. 
POLYGON ((-122.143636 47.257808, -122.143685 47.257807, -122.143877 47.257802, -122.143993 47.257799, -122.143989 47.257746,
If I changed the value to "hello world" the cookie was successful.
Thank you for your help on this.