# How to store raw json value in Cookie object?

Tags: c#, .net

I am having pretty straightforward issue, still wasn't able to find any solution. Not even sure there is any, so i better ask.

.net doesn't allow me to set cookie value in raw json format. I know i have the option to url encode it, but in this case the website won't accept such encoded cookie, so that's isn't an option.

thanks for every help ...

error i am getting:

> The 'Value'='{\"a\": \"b\"}' part of the cookie is invalid.

```
_container.Cookies.Add(new Cookie
{
     Name = "name",
     Value = "{\"a\": \"b\"}",
     Domain = "xyz.com",
     Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(10)
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store an object in a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617799/how-to-store-an-object-in-a-cookie)

Comment: @KobyDouek show me where is that one dealing with this error and raw json value