# I can't get cookies with asp .net core

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

please tell me how to solve the problem: I can't get a cookie through the controller, I get null all the time. Cookies properties don't even contain it, but if you change the cookie value from {"2":3} to {2:3}, it immediately reads it and assigns it to the cookieValue variable. But I have cookies in JSON so I don't know how to solve the problem Here is the cookie and the code to get it:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Confirm()
    {

        HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("CartItems", out var cookieValue); // cookieValue == null
        var cart = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, int>>(cookieValue);

        //other code
    }
```

[This is how my cookie have view](https://imgur.com/a/bpbRDjn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because [cookie is just string data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617830). And we could see the code here:

[image]

and [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-net-cookie-ctor(system-string-system-string)) here:

> Initializes a new instance of the Cookie class with a specified Name
> and Value.
>
> `public Cookie (string name, string? value);`

But `{"2":3}` is not a string. When we use `{2:3}`, it can be converted to string automatically and that's why we are able to get it in our code.

[image]
[image]

We could only try to serialize it as a string. Here we changed the cookie value from `{"2":3}` to `{%222%22:3}`

[image]